# AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'quad' in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, scipy

```
from scipy import linalg
from scipy.integrate import quad
import numpy as np


a = integrate.quad(lambda x: x**2, 0, 4.5)
print(a)
```

---

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-132-c7f6592004af> in <module>()
      2 from scipy.integrate import quad
      3 import numpy as np
----> 4 a = integrate.quad(lambda x: x**2, 0, 4.5)
      5 
      6 

AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'quad'
```

I have no idea what happen, anyone could help me? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code imports `quad`; You don't need to qualify it:

```
from scipy.integrate import quad  # <----
....

a = quad(lambda x: x**2, 0, 4.5)
```